# Cannot find template 'rmq-template'

Tags: ruby, rubymotion, rmq

I am trying to get started with RMQ but getting this error while creating my app. I followed the instructions of installing the gem and then creating a project. Where should I get the necessary `rmq-template` from?

```
~/motionapps $ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
~/motionapps $ motion --version
2.24
~/motionapps $ rmq -v
0.5.6
~/motionapps $ rmq create my_new_app
Cloning into '/Users/ethan/Library/RubyMotion/template/rmq-template'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
     Creating app
Cannot find template `rmq-template' in /Library/RubyMotion/lib/motion/project/template or /Users/ethan/Library/RubyMotion/template. Available templates: gem, ios, osx, promotion-template

      Complete. Things you should do:
      > cd my_new_app
      > bundle
      > rake spec
      > rake
      (main)> exit

      Then try these:
      > rake retina=3.5
      > rake retina=4 
      > rake device_family=ipad 
      > rake device
```

What should I do different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with you github.com connection, do you have account there? My problem was with missing ssh public key which I have to add to my github account

Here you have more details about 'Permission denied (publickey)' problem:
https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey